# SQLAlchemy - How to query 3 tables (with association table)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables (SQLAlchemy classes): Team, Game, and GameObserver. Each game has 2 playing teams (offense & defense) but many observing teams.

**What query would return all observers (teams) of games where the offensive team email was foo@email123.com?**

```
class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)

class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    offense_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    defense_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    offense = db.relationship('Team', 
        foreign_keys=[offense_id], backref='offensive_games')
    defense = db.relationship('Team', 
        foreign_keys=[defense_id], backref='defensive_games')

class GameObserver(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    observer_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('team.id'))
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('game.id'))
    game = db.relationship('Game', 
        foreign_keys=[game_id], backref='game_watchers')
    observer = db.relationship('Team', 
        foreign_keys=[observer_id], backref='watched_games')
```

One solution that I found works is:

```
db.session.query(Game.id, Team.email).filter(GameObserver.observer_id == 
    Team.id).filter(GameObserver.game_id == Game.id).filter(Game.offense.has(email = 
        'foo@email123.com')).all()
```

However, I suspect there is a better way to do this using joins. Does anyone have a better approach?

Comment: Would you rather have a single non-repeating list of Teams, or each actual GameObservation record?

Comment: I'd like the output to contain 2 columns (observer team email & game id) and 1 row for each observer-game.  So I guess it's the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return a row for each GameObserver record that matches your criteria.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

off_Team = aliased(Team)
obs_Team = aliased(Team)

results = db.session.query(obs_Team.email, Game.id)\
    .select_from(GameObserver)\
    .join(Game)\
    .join(obs_Team, GameObserver.observer)\
    .join(off_Team, Game.offense)\
    .filter(off_Team.email == 'foo@email123.com')\
    .all()
```

Comment: Great!  This was close... only change is aliased needs to be imported from sqlalchemy.orm rather than sqlalchemy.

I'm curious which approach (join or non-join) is more efficient.  They both yield the same output, but what's happening behind the scenes?  Which will yield better performance as the application scales?  Thanks, Brendan!